# How I identify the iOS File App directory Path?

Tags: ios, iphone, flutter

I'm developing files backup application with Flutter UI Framework. I'm not able to find the iOS Files App directory path, how'll I identify the path?

Comment: What files are you trying to back up?  An app can only access its own files.

Comment: Documents like pdf, docx, and xlsx etc. From this app "https://apps.apple.com/us/app/files/id1232058109"

Comment: You would need the user to grant permissions to the folder(s) you want to access https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/view_controllers/providing_access_to_directories

Answer (score 0):

You can build a small JavaScript share app with Scriptable app which can show you where are located app data folders and File app Folder. From there you may be able to discover file location in app.
Exemple of Scriptable script that can execute from share item in File app :

```
let fileURL = args.fileURLs[0];
let alert = new Alert()
alert.title = "Chemin fichier"
alert.message = fileURL
await alert.present()
```